# Having problems translating a curl command to Ruby Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, curl, net-http

This is a call to a Usergrid-stack web app to create a new application:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <auth_token>" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -X POST -d '{ "name":"myapp" }' \
     http://<node ip>:8080/management/orgs/<org_name>/apps
```

Here's my Ruby code:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://#{server.ipv4_address}:8080/management/orgs/#{form.org_name}/apps")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, {'Authorization' => 'Bearer #{form.auth_token}', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
request.set_form({"name" => form.app_name})
command.output.puts uri.request_uri
response = http.request(request)
```

Currently I'm getting this response from the server:

```
{\"error\":\"auth_unverified_oath\",\"timestamp\":1383613556291,\"duration\":0,\"exception\":\"org.usergrid.rest.exceptions.SecurityException\",\"error_description\":\"Unable to authenticate OAuth credentials\"}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line--

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, {'Authorization' => 'Bearer #{form.auth_token}', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

Try changing that authorization string to `"Bearer #{form.auth_token}"`--with double quotes. String interpolation only works with double-quoted strings.